# Is it possible to have a charge-offs deleted after paying it off?

Tags: credit-card

I have 3 charge-offs that I haven't paid for several months due to the fact my income hasn't been strong to cover the monthly payments. Is it possible to arrange to have the charge-offs deleted before I agree to pay them off completely? I started paying them off because I got laid off so I stopped making payments.

Comment: Define CO, please. The answer is almost certainly no, but....

Comment: CO = Charge Off?  Creditor Obligation?

Comment: For certain, your best course of action would have been to contact the person/orginaization you made this "CO" with when you were laid off.  People lose jobs all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Once your accounts went delinquent, there's no changing it.  The creditors are going to report the defaults regardless of whether they're paid or not. They will show the balance as paid, but the consequences of the defaults will still be there.

That being said, it is less harmful to your credit that at least you paid the debts off rather than leaving them as open collections, because that's really bad.

For future's sake, you're far better off trying to make arrangements with creditors for perhaps lower payments for a short period if you're having difficulties than not paying them at all.  Most creditors will work with you to make an arrangement rather than letting the debt go bad, because oftentimes once people start missing payments, they quit paying altogether, and the creditor loses out.  They can send the debt to collections, but they'll get far less than the amount owed assuming it is ever recovered.

This is just one of those life lessons about credit that we all have to learn, preferably by seeing other peoples' experiences.

As long as you keep your bills current from here out, the damage of the defaults will diminish over time, although other creditors will still see them.

I hope this helps.

Good luck!